bash to delete backwards using esc+backspace till the slash on prompt
am new to bash (used tcsh till now) and I would like that using esc+backspace that the cursor will delete backwards till the very next slash (like I had in tcsh).
I tried several scripts from different AI engines with no success. For example, I have the following prompt:
> ls hello_1_2/hello_1_2_3

If unix cursor is in the end of the line and I am using esc+backspace, I would expect that it will end up with:
> ls hello_1_2/

Current behavior is
> ls hello_1_2/hello_1_2_

Appreciate your help.

You can just simulate the keypress:  xdotool key esc+backspace and use a key combo to get the desired result.

Not sure I understand xdotool function. anyway when I run it - it does not recognize the commands.
> xdotool key esc+backspace    -> (symbol) No such key name 'esc'. Ignoring it.
> xdotool key Esc+Backspace    -> (symbol) No such key name 'Esc'. Ignoring it.

Here's the list of keycodes.  Looks like it's Escape

now there are no errors but still it will not do the expected behaviour. I am not sure how do I set it to work as expected. should I set anything else rather then xdotool key Esc+BackSpace?

The readline library provides a unix-filename-rubout function that does exactly what you want, so it should be enough to put
"\e\b": unix-filename-rubout

(\e = Escape, \b = Backspace) in your .inputrc file.

Unfortunately , it is not working :(. Still see the same behavior.
I placed it as the last row .inputrc file.

please see I edit the original message with introducing the current behavior.

@user8253554 You started a new shell to check? And are you sure the expectation in your edit is what you want?

Sorry. I re-edited again. it was wrong .
Yes I started a new shell.
